# jQuery getAttribute

Tags: jquery

i have an "uid" attribute and it's value on my "body" tag...

```
$(document).ready(regFunct());

function regFunct(){
   alert($("body").attr("uid"));
}
```

but it says "undefined". something wrong?

Comment: @bolt:yeah i know that, i have  another "id" attribute in the body tag... i need another variable to be saved on the body tag

Comment: I wouldn't add a new attribute to the body element. Take a look at jQuery.data() - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     regFunct();
 });

function regFunct(){
     alert($("body").attr("uid"));
 }
```

Comment: Or even $(function(){ regFunct();});

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot:it's return the undefined too... it's return an alert box and says "undefined";

Comment: you shouldn't not answer the question, because adding custom attribute is a bad behavior. I -1 your answer

Comment: @Baptiste do you know why he is using custom attribute? Or even if he needs a lesson on best practice?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot, if someone asks me how to sink his boat in order to swim in the sea, I will teach that there must be a better way :)

Comment: @all:i produce this attribute from the php uid="<?php echo $_GET[uid] ?>"

Comment: @Baptiste then you can take @raRaRa's approach. See his comment under question.

Comment: @Afrig Aminuddin, I updated the .data method with the <?php echo $_GET[uid] ?> example

Answer (score 2):

You are putting the return-value from `regFunct` into the `.ready()` handler method. That is, `undefined` because your function does not return anything.

You need to pass in the function reference, by omitting the parenthesis:

```
$(document).ready(regFunct);
```

Comment: @AfrigAminuddin: the only explanation then is, that your `<body>` tag does not own a property "uid": Working example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/PkngP/

Comment: It's undefined in Internet Explorer because the uid attribute is not a valid attribute for the body tag. Look at my answer for solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hi adding custom attribute is a bad behavior. have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_body.asp you will no uid attribute.

If you want to store you own data. use `$.data` (see documentation in [jQuery site](http://api.jquery.com/data))

```
// save the value
$('body').data('uid', mycustomvalue);
// retrieve the value
$('body').data('uid');
```

If the data come from the server, you can still do

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
      $('body').data('uid', '<?php echo $_GET[uid] ?>');
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(regFunct);
```

set to rel tag and check!

```
function regFunct(){
   alert($("body").attr("rel"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: It seems to be undefined in Internet Explorer since uid is not a known attribute. The fix would be to use the `jQuery.data()` to insert data to an element.

```
$(document).ready(regFunct());

function regFunct(){
    $('body').data('uid', 1337);
    alert($('body').data('uid'));
}
```

But you would have to assign the uid yourself. For example you could do it via `<script>` on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(setData());

    function setData(){
        $('body').data('uid', 1337);
    }
</script>
```

More on jQuery.data() on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6Bwtt/1/

BUT if you are trying to save data on the page from the server-side, you could just have some invisible element after the body, for example `<div id="uid" style="display:none;">Your ID here</div>` then fetch it using `$("#uid").html();` Voila! :)

Comment: @ Baptiste Pernet - Sure, you could use javascript to store all the data you need, but sometimes people like simple solution that works without much trouble. Some people seem to have trouble finding a way on how to do this: $('body').data('uid', yourServerSideID).