# Extract href from string with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

What would be the easiest way with regex to extract the `href` string containing a stylesheet link and save it to a variable in JavaScript?

The stylesheet is a string and not a real stylesheet link. It's intended to be inserted with Javascript after the page loads.

EDIT:

```
    <script>
        // Loading stylesheet just before body closes
        $(function() {
            var stylesheet = '<link href="/Static/css/compiled/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>';
            var stylesheetHref = ""; // WANT TO SET THIS!!

            if (document.createStyleSheet) {
                document.createStyleSheet(stylesheetHref);
            } else {
                $("head").append(stylesheet));
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried the `getAttribute()` method?

Comment: Oooh, so it's a string an not a real stylesheet, makes sense no, but how should we know what that even looks like, or how to get it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery getAttribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792196/jquery-getattribute)

Comment: that's not a stylesheet, that's a string :^)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not create elements the proper way and just start out with the href in a variable ?

```
$(function () {
    var href = '/Static/css/compiled/styles.css';
    var stylesheet = $('<link />', {rel: 'stylesheet', href: href});

    $("head").append(stylesheet);
});
```

Comment: @Archer - Yes I did, got the tags a little mixed up.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a stylesheet link in string format then this will get you the href value, very easily without regex...

```
var link = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css" />';
var href = $(link).attr("href");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
    // Loading stylesheet just before body closes
    $(function() {
        var stylesheet = '<link href="/Static/css/compiled/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>';
        var stylesheetHref = stylesheet.replace(/.*href="(.*?)".*/i, "$1");


        if (document.createStyleSheet) {
            document.createStyleSheet(stylesheetHref);
        } else {
            $("head").append(stylesheet));
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @ejay, and why is that ?

Comment: @Ejay Time is your most precious asset, don't waste it!

Comment: Is it me or your comment is quite ironic?

Comment: @ejay, I was serious and ironic in a positive way! Enjoy your day;)

Comment: you too man. Chill out :) This comment/edit timing thing happens all the time :)